# Python documentation: iterable many times?

Tags: python, duck-typing

In documenting a Python function, I find it more Pythonic to say:

```
def Foo(i):
    """i: An interable containing…"""
```

…rather than…

```
def Foo(i):
    """i: A list of …"""
```

When `i` really doesn't need to be a `list`. (`Foo` will happily operate on a `set`, `tuple`, etc.) The problem is generators. Generators typically only allow 1 iteration. *Most* functions are OK with generators or iterables that only allow a single pass, but some are not.

For those functions that cannot accept generators/things that can only be iterated once, is there a clear, consistent Python term to say "thing that can only be iterated more than once"?

The Python glossary for [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) and [iterator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterator) seem to have a "once, but maybe more if you're lucky" definition.

Comment: A “collection”?  It seems to describe all the example types here.

Comment: +1 to the usage of container, that seems to capture the underlying idea in the most concise way, but...I don't think I've seen "container" used in any Python documentation?

Comment: A container is an object with a `__contains__()` method, which is neither necessary nor sufficient for a reusable iterable. http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a standard term for this, at least not offhand, but I think "reusable iterable" would get the point across if you need a short phrase.

In practice, it's generally possible to structure your function so that you don't need to iterate over `i` more than once. Alternatively, you can create a list out of the iterable and then iterate over the list as many times as you want; or you can use `itertools.tee` to get multiple independent "copies" of the iterator. That lets you accept a generator even if you do need to use it more than once.

Comment: Note that, as pointed out in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), "In general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use list() instead of tee()." In that case, `tee()` will copy/store the content several times whereas `list()` will only store it once.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more a matter of style and preference than anything else, yet... I have a different take on my documentation: **I always write the docstring according to the expected input in the context of the program**.

Example: if I wrote a function that expect to go over keys of a dictionary and ignore its values I write:

```
arg : a dictionary of...
```

even if `for e in arg:` would work with other iterables. I chose to do so, because within the context of my code, I don't care if the function would *still work*... I care more that whoever reads the documentation understand how that function is *meant to be used*.

On the other hand, if I am writing a *utility function* that can cope with a wide spectrum of iterables by design, I go one of these two ways:

1. **document what kind of exception** will be rose under certain conditions [ex: *"Raise TypeError if the iterable can't be iterated more than once"*]
2. **perform some pre-emptive argument handling** that will make the function compatible with 'once-only' iterables.

In other words, I try to **either make my function solid enough to handle edge cases, or to be very outspoken on its limitations**.

Again: there's nothing wrong with the approach you want to take, but I consider this one of the cases in which "[explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)": a documentation in which is mentioned "reusable iterable" is definitively accurate, but the adjective could easily be overlooked.

HTH!